# Ubuntu 18.04 installation issues on a new PC with Windows 10 alredy installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I am quite new to Linux so cut me some slack for my ignorance.

I have been facing issues, trying to install ubuntu on a new PC build with:

A Ryzen 3 2200g Apu,

HyperX Fury 8gb ram,

Gigabyte A350M HD3 Motherboard.

The live USB normally fails to boot giving, an error, 1 table failed to load, or something.

Sometimes if I try 'Load optimized defaults' It does boot but normally it ends up on a black screen.

By some luck, if I was able to initiate the installer, it does not detect Windows. 
When I tried to proceed with the install, it said that my wifi did not work, but Firefox on the live cd did work and later, it failed to install grub.

According to a few searches, the Ryzen processors and The AB350M motherboards do have issues running Linux...

Any Ideas about what should I do to get Ubuntu properly working?

I apologize for being so low-effort in this post but I am desperate.

Regards

Comment: It's been known for a while that Ryzen support is not great. You've not asked anything. What can we do for you?

Comment: Provide a solution and a possible explanation as to why Ubuntu is not installing properly and what should I do.

Comment: "Provide a solution" is easier said then done. There is no magic word for it. I can only repeat myself, Ryzen support has been cooking, it is not quite done, and you know that. You probably can't do much about it, don't lose hope, and try again in six months or so.